# Jmeter config ramp-down

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

In Jmeter, I'm able to set ramp-up after creating a thread group, but How can I set ramp-down for a script. I couldn't find anywhere to do it. Could you help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: why do you need to do a ramp down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `Thread Group` does not provide ramp-down option.

You can use `Stepping Thread Group` or `Ultimate Thread Group`

You can download those plugins from this location - http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/